# Is this synchronized block need?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is the synchronized block on `System.out.println(number);` need the following code?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Main {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    private static long number = 0L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Worker worker = new Worker(doneSignal);
            worker.start();
        }

        doneSignal.await();

        synchronized (LOCK) { // Is this synchronized block need?
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    private static class Worker extends Thread {

        private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;

        private Worker(CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
            this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                number += 1;
            }
            doneSignal.countDown();
        }

    }
}
```

I think it's need because there is a possibility to read the cached value.

But some person say that:

It's unnecessary.
Because when the main thread reads the variable `number`, all of worker thread has done the write operation in memory of variable `number`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doneSignal.await()` is a blocking call, so your `main()` will only proceed when all your `Worker` threads have called `doneSignal.countDown()`, making it reach 0, which is what makes the `await()` method return.

There is no point adding that `synchronized` block before the `System.out.println()`, all your threads are already done at that point.

Consider using an `AtomicInteger` for `number` instead of synchronizing against a lock to call `+= 1`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if threads are done or not, it's matter if reader can see actual number value. Luckily, pair countdown()+await() guarantees happens before :)

Comment: all that matters for `doneSignal.await()` is that the `CountDownLatch` reaches 0, what happens to `number` doesn't matter at all. If he removed the `CountDownLatch` altogether, the main thread might actually be done before all his `Worker` threads are done, depending on the scheduler, and print either `0` or some other number

Comment: I think **qwwdfsad**'s point is that if there wasn't *happens-before* between the code before each `countDown()` and the code after `await()`, you could still see value less than 10 for `number`. If for example `await()` worked by checking a value which was updated with the old (pre-Java 5.0) `volatile` semantics, it could reliably see that all threads have finished, but it could not reliably see the last value of `number`.

Comment: thanks @DimitarDimitrov , I now get what qwwdfsad was referring to. However, those threads do call `countDown()`, so "being done" includes signaling, which is what guarantees _happens-before_

Comment: No problems @micheleb - no one's arguing that there's no *happens-before*. What I (and I assume @qwwdfsad) am arguing is that the *happens-before* edge is the main reason why synchronization is not needed when printing the result, not the fact that all the threads are done.

Comment: Thanks **michele b**, **qwwdfsad** and **Dimitar Dimitrov**.

I clearly understand that:
There is no need of synchronized block around "System.out.println(number)" because of the guarantees of _happens-before_.

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov I guess that the misunderstanding came from the "being done" part: I meant it as "being done with the task the threads are synchronizing on" (hence why that "_which they signal..._" part) whereas you and qwwdfsad interpreted it as "threads exiting".

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary:

```
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Worker worker = new Worker(doneSignal);
  worker.start();
}
doneSignal.await();
// here the only thread running is the main thread
```

Just before dying each thread countDown the countDownLatch

```
@Override
public void run() {
  synchronized (LOCK) {
    number += 1;
  }
  doneSignal.countDown();
}
```

Only when the 10 thread finish their job the doneSignal.await(); line will be surpass.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary because you are waiting for "done" signal. That flush memory in a way that all values from the waited thread become visible to main thread.

However you can test that easily, make inside the `run` method a computation that takes several (millions) steps and don't get optimized by the compiler, if you see a value different than from the final value that you expect then your final value was not already visible to main thread. Of course here the critical part is to make sure the computation doesn't get optimized so a simple "increment" is likely to get optimized. This in general is usefull to test concurrency where you are not sure if you have correct memory barriers so it may turn usefull to you later.

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` is not needed around `System.out.println(number);`, but not because the `PrintWriter.println()` implementations are internally synchronized or because by the time `doneSignal.await()` unblocks all the worker threads have finished.

`synchronized` is not needed because there's a *happens-before* edge between everything before each call to `doneSignal.countDown` and the completion of `doneSignal.await()`. This guarantees that you'll successfully see the correct value of `number`.

Answer (score -1):

**Needed**

No.

However, as there is no (documented) guarantee that there will not be any interleaving it is *possible* to find log entries interleaved.

```
System.out.println("ABC");
System.out.println("123");
```

**could** print:

```
AB1
23C
```

**Worthwhile**

Almost certainly not. Most JVMs will implement `println` with a lock [open JDK does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintWriter.java#PrintWriter.print%28java.lang.String%29).

**Edge case**

As suggested by @DimitarDimitrov, there is one further possible use for that lock and it is to ensure a memory barrier is crossed befor accessing `number`. If that is the concern then you do not need to `lock`, all you need to do is make `number` `volatile`.

```
private static volatile long number = 0L;
```

Comment: OP's concern is related to seeing a correctly updated value for `number`. This concern cannot be solved by `println()` implementations being `synchronized` (unless the updates to `number` are done while in the same monitor, which most probably is `System.out`).

Comment: About your `volatile` update - `volatile` is entirely redundant in OP's example if `doneSignal.await()` is kept. In its current form, your answer doesn't really look correct (or at least it's unclear how it applies to the original question).